# How do I update newsletter subscription with Magento API

Tags: api, newsletter

I tried to update it with the following values:

PUT https://example.com/rest/V1/customers/3

BODY

```
{
  "customer": {
    "id": "47",
    "email": "info@example.com",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Johnson",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "extension_attributes": {
     "is_subscribed": true
    }
  }
}
```

I get a 200 respond back but the newsletter update didn't update to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can't set `is_subscribed` by the customer API because what determines if a customer is subscribed to the newsletter is actually determined by the `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber` Model. So if you want to do this via api you'll need to create a custom API call to do such. Here's a quick module I threw together for you.

**Create a new module**

> *<Vendor>_Newsletter*

**Create module.xml file**

> *app/code/<Vendor>/Newsletter/etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Newsletter" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Newsletter" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Create webapi.xml file**

> *app/code/<Vendor>/Newsletter/etc/webapi.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/newsletter/subscribe/:email" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" method="subscribe"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Newsletter::subscriber"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Now you should be able to subscribe a customer by simply making a API `GET` request to `https://your_magento_store.com/rest/V1/newsletter/subscribe/info@example.com`. This will call `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::subscribe` and pass in the email provided in the request uri as the parameter to the function.